# Number Formatting String

Tags: c#, .net

I want to make round a number to million. This is my code:

```
    string formating = "#,#,,";
    decimal abc = 1234567890m;
    decimal abc2 = 0m;
    string text = abc.ToString(formating); // text="1,235"
    string text2 = abc2.ToString(formating); // text2=""
```

How to correct formatting so that `text2="0"`?

P/S: I use C# .Net 2.0.

Comment: Please fix my formating string, because if abc2=0, text2="", but I want text2="0". Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `#,0,,`.

Note that the number will be rounded, similar behaviour to your original format string:

```
Console.WriteLine(0m.ToString("#,0,,"));             //     0
Console.WriteLine(499999m.ToString("#,0,,"));        //     0
Console.WriteLine(500000m.ToString("#,0,,"));        //     1
Console.WriteLine(1234567890m.ToString("#,0,,"));    // 1,235
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `string formating = "#,##0"`

Then you can write:

```
    string text = (abc/1000000).ToString(formating); // text="1,235" 
    string text2 = (abc2/1000000).ToString(formating); // text2="0"
```